# Passing Events in ReactJS Form

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-props

I'm trying to make a component with React and I have 2 classes ( the App class that has the state and the ImageType class that has a dropdown using select and option).
I want to change the state in the App when I make a selection in the ImageType class but I get the error (out.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined).
I know that I'm doing something wrong but I can't realize what.
I want the "value" of the option tag to became the new value of this.state.field
Thank you

```
class ImageType extends React.Component{

    onDone=()=>{
        if(typeof this.props.done === "function"){
            this.props.done(this.props.imageType)
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <select value={this.props.imageType} onChange={this.onDone}>
                    <option value="illustration">Illustration</option>
                    <option value="vector">Vector</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

class App extends React.Component{

    state={
        field:""
    }

    done = (event) =>{
        this.setState({
            field: event.target.value
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <ImageType imageType={this.state.field} done={this.done}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If I put everything in the App class it works. The project has a bable plugin so i dont need to delclare constructor in class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ImageComponent` you have to pass **event** in `onDone` function:

```
// replaced brackets with event
onDone = event => {
  if(typeof this.props.done === "function"){
    this.props.done(event)
  }
}
```

Comment: It works thank you very much. If is not to much can you please tell me why we pass the event. In other cases when I modify the state from a child component i do it like I did it in be example above ( ex: i have a button in a different class )

Comment: Because you have the **event argument** in the App component **done** function. The other solution is to pass **this.props.done(event.target.value)** and to use argument **field** as App **done** function argument as cary suggested.

Answer (score 0):

@Spartacus are right, since `this.props.done` function accepts a `event` parameter, you shouldn't pass a `this.props.imageType` which is not `event` type.

Or you can just pass the selected image type to the callback in the `App` component.

## ImageType component

```
onDone = event => {
  if (typeof this.props.done === "function") {
    this.props.done(event.target.value);
}};
```

pass the selected value to the callback function in App component,

## App component

```
done = imageType => {
  this.setState({
    field: imageType
});};
```

[check the demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-bird-focsk)

Comment: @NameHere , let's work it through step by step. 

1. select the image type

2. onDone triggered in ImageType component

3. onDone triggered in App component

4. this.setState on onDone in App component called with `event.target.value` which is `imageType.target.value` which will cause the error, since imageType.target is undefined due to the fact that imageType is a string.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, If i just copy paste the answer not knowing why something is done in a certain way I will never leran

Comment: @ NameHere, it's unidirectional data flow in React, so if you want to change the state in a parent from children, you need to pass the callback to the children and children will call it with some data, then the actual function will use the data to set the state. For example, you select a new image type then `onDone` in ImageType will be called with image type, say "vector", which in turn `onDone` in App will be called with "vector", which is the function that takes and processes the argument "vector" to set the state, then App re-renders, pass the new state to ImageType.